# What should I use as an alternative to System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary (3.5)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I require a thread safe collection but are unable to use ConcurrentDictionary as its .NET 4.0, and I need to use .NET 3.5. What are alternatives are out there?

Comment: And which version would you be using?

Comment: Targeting 3.5,   ConcurrentDictionary is 4.0 (sorry misleading title)

Comment: Can always fall back to wrapping the standard dictionary in a class that uses locks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I found what I was after. A nuget package of the TPL backported to 3.5. It can be found here
http://nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this article

[“Thread safe” Dictionary(TKey,TValue)](http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/02/25/thread-safe-dictionarytkeytvalue/)

Comment: +1 for link to the article, because (typically) it is not just about sticking a lock around all operations of a regular dictionary. You might want to "extract" some key points into your answer though.

Answer (score 3):

For Framework 3.5 I see the following options:

- *Dictionary* + [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Simple wrap to *lock*
- *Dictionary* + [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Better than the previous one, because has got read and write locks. So several threads can read, and just one - write.
- *Dictionary* + [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It's just optimisation of the previous one.
- [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). From my experience, it's the slowest method. Check [Hashtable.Synchronized()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, it's a ready to go solution from Microsoft.

I would use *Dictionary* + *ReaderWriterLock* or *ReaderWriterLockSlim*.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple wrapper and only implement what you need. Keep in mind that it is not thread safe to perform an operation on a Dictionary that relies on the result of a previous call. This is exemplified in the `TryAdd` method.

```
class ConcurrentMap<K, V>
{
    readonly Dictionary<K, V> _map = new Dictionary<K, V>();

    public bool TryGetValue(K key, out V value)
    {
        lock (_map)
        {
            return _map.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
    }

    public bool TryAdd(K key, V value)
    {
        lock (_map)
        {
            if (!_map.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _map.Add(key, value);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool TryRemove(K key)
    {
        lock (_map)
        {
            return _map.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed that for .Net 3.5... someone's still there back :)

adding my class, added some more functionality than previous attached codes.

```
 public class SafeDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{

    private readonly object _Padlock = new object();

    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_Padlock)
            {
                return _Dictionary[key];
            }
        }

        set
        {
            lock (_Padlock)
            {
                _Dictionary[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
            return _Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);

    }
public bool TryAdd(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    lock (_Padlock)
    {
        if (!_Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _Dictionary.Add(key, value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
  }

public bool TryRemove(TKey key)
{
    lock (_Padlock)
    {
        return _dictionary.Remove(key);
    }
}
}

    internal void Add(TKey key, TValue val)
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
        {
            _Dictionary.Add(key, val);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey id)
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
            return _Dictionary.ContainsKey(id);
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> OrderBy(Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, TKey> func)
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
            return _Dictionary.OrderBy(func).ToList();
    }

    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection Values
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_Padlock)
                return _Dictionary.Values;
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection Keys
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_Padlock)
                return _Dictionary.Keys;
        }
    }





    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
            return _Dictionary.GetEnumerator();

    }



    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
            return _Dictionary.GetEnumerator();

    }
}
```